# django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: python, django, postgresql

while trying to connect my postgresql database with django i'm facing this error django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

this is my settings.py

```
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_USER_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
    }
}`
```

this is my .env file

```
export DB_NAME=demo
export DB_USER=postgres
export DB_USER_PASSWORD=12345678
export DB_HOST=localhost
```

Comment: Django does not automatically read the `.env` file.  How are you loading those variables into the environment?

Comment: And that's the wrong format for `.env` files anyway.  You don't need `export`.

Comment: `os.environ.get()` gets the value from `env`, the `.env` file does not put the value in `env`. My guess is you looking for [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/).

Answer (score 0):

First install the Python Decouple library by running `pip install python-decouple`. Then type the following in your .env file

```
DB_NAME=demo
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=12345678
DB_HOST=localhost
```

Ensure that these are your correct database credentials.
In your settings.py, import the library:

`from decouple import config`

then retrieve the settings parameters:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

See https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html